# Button's target is always "self"? Can I set to be another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible or not to set button's target to be another thing than "self"?
Such as UIView or UIWindow??

I tried but I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS as error.

Comment: Can you add the exact crash log that you got? And more importantly, what you tried (code) that crashed the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the target to any `instance/object`. The instance/object should respond to the selector you set. Otherwise you will get the SIGABRT exception.

Mostly we set the target to our custom view controllers, because we do some operations on some events. We set `Self` as target if we defined the action in the current view controller. You can set it some other view controller like the following,

```
AViewController *a = [[AViewController alloc] init];
[yourButton addTarget:a action:@selector(onButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When you click on the `yourButton` the action `onButtonPressed:` of the view controller instance `a` will be triggered. *Note: AViewController should implement the method `onButtonPressed:`*. You will receive SIGABRT, if not.

Comment: instance of a view controller? Can you give me some sample? I got program received signal "SIGABRT", after I assigned target as instance controller. My button is in global and call the global function in the same .m file

Comment: thank you, EmptyStack. I can did it by followed your instruction but my problem still not be totally solved. As you said, controller should implement the method, but I use global method in the different file. I put global method in header(eg. Global.h) then  I imported Global.h to AViewController but the program kind of freeze. I wonder why?

Comment: @SomethingLikesNothing, What code you are using to set the target-action?

Comment: @EmptyStack,....I don't understand your question well. In Global.m, I have void function which I tried to call in AViewController class. My button is also in Global.m

Comment: @SomethingLikesNothing, Post the code where you get SIGBART exception

Comment: @EmptyStack, I did not got SIGBART exception after I followed your previous adivce. The problem that I got is....when I press global button to call global method in AViewController, My application was freeze (no activated after I touched) but there is no error in XCode. This is how I call method. Button -> AViewController.methodA() -> inside methodA() has global method

Comment: @EmptyStack, I found that why it is freezing. In the Global function, I call AViewController.methodA() too. Silly of mine....So sorry. However I got the error from Xcode that SIGBRT exception(Terminate callled after throwing an instance of "NSException"

Comment: @EmptyStack. Ah... I am not Alright. Since it is still not work as I planned.I got SIGBRT exception when I called global function in class. One more question, "action:@selector(onButtonPressed:)" which you wrote. Why you put ":" after method "onButtonPressed"? without ":", the program is worked anyway.

Comment: @SomethingLikesNothing, Actually the colon(`:`) is not neccessary. But, if you've defined the method as `- (void)onButtonPressed:(id)sender`, you have to use the colon there. The button will be automatically sent as the argument to that function. You can just leave the colon if your method signature doesn't contain any argument

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors, 
it resolved with the change of [AViewController class] as target.

```
[yourButton addTarget:[AViewController class] action:@selector(onButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

My class is also declared as + sign, because its a library to use in all apps.

```
@interface SocialClass : NSObject

+ (void) gotoYoutube;
+ (void) gotoFacebook;
+ (void) gotoTwiter;

@end
```